# Через несколько дней перестает авторизировать пользователя, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, регистрация, аутентификация

Сделал авторизацию на Laravel, все оки, регистрирует, авторизирует, но... Почему-то спустя пару дней (более глубокую закономерность пока не заметил) перестает авторизировать, хотя юзер точно есть в бд, все токены есть, пароль есть, ничего не менялось. 
Регистрирую нового - все ок, и через несколько дней снова нельзя войти.

Понятия не имею куда копать, с чем это связано?

Comment: _все токены есть_ может в токене expiration date прописано?

Comment: подскажите, как это проверить?

Comment: у вас JWT токен генерируется для пользователя?

Comment: не особо в этом разбираюсь, я использовал из коробки php artisan make:auth 
судя по всему обычный токен

Comment: Вы единственная связь между нами и вашей проблемой. Когда на вопрос вы отвечаете - я не разбираюсь, я не знаю или не понимаю, как мы тогда можем вам помочь? заливайте тогда на публичный гит... либо сперва разберитесь как оно работает (а не просто прописывайте бездумно команды), а потом спрашивайте что, как и почему.

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы. спросил в расчете на то, что это окажется интуитивно понятным и что такое уже было у кого-то, но видимо проблема индвидуальная. Буду изучать тему и разбираться

Comment: свазано это с хешем пароля. если создать новую регистрацию с паролем, как было на предыдущей и вручную в бд скопировать его хеш на место предыдущего - тот пользователь может авторизироваться. 
Если проблема с хешем, почему тогда сразу вход работает и еще какое-то время тоже, а потом перестает